# showBluetoothAccessoryPicker returns error 2

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios-bluetooth

Using the following code:

```
EAAccessoryManager.SharedAccessoryManager.ShowBluetoothAccessoryPicker(null,HandleAction1);

void HandleAction1(NSError obj)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("HandleAction1");
}
```

Returns:

> {The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (EABluetoothAccessoryPickerErrorDomain error 2.)}

Comment: Error code 2 indicates that the picker was cancelled.  Where in your app is this code being called?

Comment: At startup. It is canceled because the list is empty.

Comment: There are BT devices connected.

Comment: The picker will only show MFi accessories, not general Bluetooth accessories like handsfree devices or speakers.  I just tried it in `viewDidAppear` and the picker was shown until I cancelled it, giving an error 2 as expected.

Comment: What library are you supposed to use instead?

Comment: There is no library for managing or connecting to legacy Bluetooth peripherals from within an app.  The user is expected to manage this in the device settings.  You can discover and connect to BLE devices using Core Bluetooth.  You can select audio devices using `AVRoutePickerView`

Comment: AAARG!!! APPLE!!!!  Why would you provide a library that does not work for common peripherals—and if you make it this useless, why wouldn’t you CLEARLY document this.

Comment: It is documented; see the note in my answer.  The External Accessory framework isn't "useless", it does what it is intended to do; lets you work with MFi accessories

Comment: I have read hours of pages including Apple dev docs.  Nowhere is it made clear that this library only works for a certain group of devices. All the examples leave this little tidbit out-and since the majority of devices are not MFI, it is useless for common app development intended for the masses who may or may not have an MFi device, apparently I own none, and have no idea how to get one.

Comment: This is a little strange as the current MFI documentation says devices supporting standard bluetooth protocol devices don't need MFI certification, only hard wired ones do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library only works with MFI devices. It WILL NOT work with the majority of common devices. It is useless for typical devices.

Answer (score 1):

You have stated that you are cancelling the displayed picker.  In this case, it is expected to receive error 2, since that is [`EABluetoothAccessoryPickerError.Code.resultCancelled`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/eabluetoothaccessorypickererror/code/resultcancelled)

You won't see standard Bluetooth accessories, such as handsfree devices or speakers, in this list; only MFi devices are shown:

> [**Note**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/externalaccessory/eaaccessorymanager/1613913-showbluetoothaccessorypicker)
>
> The picker displays only Bluetooth devices that include an iAP over Bluetooth unique ID in their extended inquiry response.

Comment: I am guessing your note is cut from docs somewhere. The statement is meaningless. Not being a BT expert, I have no idea what it means. It should be “This library only works with MFI devices. It WILL NOT work with the majority of common devices.”

Comment: The word "Note" links to the source, which is the documentation for the function you are calling.  I guess there is a certain amount of familiarity required with iOS, but it is fairly well known what the External Accessory framework is for.  Generally Apple doesn't expose settings functionality to apps that are already addressed by the system settings application